# fdisk - create swap partition that is half the disk size

Tags: linux, unix, centos, redhat, swap

I have a `/dev/xvdf disk` mounted on my linux server.
I am creating a swap partition using this disk which I am successfull in doing so.

However, what i would also like to do is partition just half the disk to use for swap, and keep the other half.

I have done the following :

```
**fdisk -l**

Disk /dev/xvdf: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

to begin the creating the swap partition :

```
fdisk /dev/xvdf
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x6ab35b7f.
```

I then went ahead and selected to make a new partition (primary) :

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
```

I then selected 1 which is the default partition number

```
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-2097151, default 2048):
Using default value 2048
```

And this is where the confusion begins for me, i intend to use only half of the total disk of **/dev/xvdf** and i did the following :

```
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-2097151, default 2097151): 536MB
Value out of range.
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-2097151, default 2097151): +536MB
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 511 MiB is set

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 82
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux swap / Solaris'

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

I have specified **536MB** on the size as shown above which is half of **/dev/xvdf** which is 1073MB.

Is this the correct way of partioning half the disk please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this question has already been answered long ago, but for future reference, I believe fdisk reads partition sizes using `M`, not `MB`. In this case, you would need to change your final partition size to `+536M`.